# Error using exam class with customized exercise layout : "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item"

Tags: lists, exam

In order to generate fancy examination documents, I usually use some custom command of mine to turn the `\section` command into exercise titles. Then, I use the `\uplevel` command for exercise introduction, when needed.

Maybe this is all like selling my soul to devil but it worked fine until I wanted some day to insert a list environment in the *very first* exercise. As an example, the compilation of the following minimal working example will stop on `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`, unless a previous exercise, **without a list environment** is inserted (uncommenting the previous lines, for instance):

```
\documentclass{exam}

\newcounter{ctr_exercises}
\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{
\refstepcounter{ctr_exercises}
\section*{Exercise \arabic{ctr_exercises}~\hrulefill~{#1}}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{questions}
%     \exercise{A preliminary exercise}
%
%     \question How are you?

    \exercise{Main exercise}

    \uplevel{Some introduction with a list environment:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item item \#1.
    \end{itemize}
    }

    \question A dreadful question.
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

What can I do in order to allow list environments for all my exercises?

Shall I consider withdrawing my customization and follow more strictly the exam class documentation? But what would be the closest equivalent of my uncommented MWE, with "authorized" commands only? (I've read the whole documentation through and never found anything satisfactory to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving `\begin{questions}`

```
\documentclass{exam}

\newcounter{ctr_exercises}
\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{
\refstepcounter{ctr_exercises}
\section*{Exercise \arabic{ctr_exercises}~\hrulefill~{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \exercise{Main exercise}
    \uplevel{itemize outside the uplevel}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item item \#1.
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{questions}
    \question A dreadful question.
\end{questions}
\exercise{second exercise}
\uplevel{itemize in the uplevel:
\begin{itemize}
  \item item \#1.
\end{itemize}}

\begin{questions}
\question A dreadful question.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This fits my expectations much better: no hack and renumbering of the questions for each exercise (seen as sections). There's even no more need for the `\uplevel` commands. :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that questions is a list and probably conflicts with itemize.  You can put the itemize inside a savebox outside the questions environment, or stop and restart questions.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\newcounter{ctr_exercises}
\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{
\refstepcounter{ctr_exercises}
\section*{Exercise \arabic{ctr_exercises}~\hrulefill~{#1}}}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% more than one line
\exercise{Main exercise}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item item \#1.
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}

  \begin{questions}
%     \exercise{A preliminary exercise}
%
%     \question How are you?
  \fullwidth{\usebox\tempbox}

    \question A dreadful question.
  \end{questions}
  \edef\savequestion{\arabic{question}}
  
  \begin{questions}
  \setcounter{question}{\savequestion}%
  \question Continue numbers.
  \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is quite some hack and the left alignment of the word "Exercise" is lost (something like `\indent` is needed right before the `minipage`). But the answer seems convenient indeed.

Comment: You want `\exercise` to be indented?   You can put it inside the questions environment, just not itemize.

Comment: You can also add indentation, but `\leftmargin` is reset inside the questions environemnt to 17,78pt.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear: these `\exercise` artifacts yields indented section titles; but the one with your hack looses this indentation. Just add another `\exercise` after the so-called "main" one with the list and you will see how it should display properly. My suggestion is to have an `\indent` in the middle of `\savebox{\tempbox}{\indent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% more than one line`. Do you agree on that addition?

Comment: Actually, it would be `\hspace*{17.78pt}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-17.78pt}%` It works, but looks weird.  Besides, didn't you use `\uplevel` for the itemize?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It's not so weird to me, since the indentation was the expected behaviour before defining the hack. I did use `\uplevel` for the `itemize`, but I don't understand why you ask that.

Comment: `\uplevel` removes the indentation one level.  (`\@totalleftmargin`)

Comment: Maybe we're talking about two different elements. I was dealing with the indentation for the exercise title only, using the `\exercise` command.